# How to save an image from a webpage in iMacros?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

I was thinking of saving images from a webpage.

So here is my code right now:

```
URL GOTO=http://www.tppcrpg.net/battle.php?Battle
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.tppcrpg.net/validate_image.php?Validate=375645145118  CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS
```

What I'm trying to do is get [this image](http://i53.tinypic.com/24b17di.png) and save it in the downloads folder. For some reason it is not giving me the dialog when I try this. Now I'm not very experienced in this so I want to know how to save images.

The `Validate` ID is different every time the page gets refreshed. However, it's in the same position of the page every time.

So since I'll be saving like millions of those images, how do I save it so that I name it a `n.png` whereas, `n` is the loop count being played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
URL GOTO=http://www.tppcrpg.net/battle.php?Battle
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\ FILE=captcha.png WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.tppcrpg.net/validate_image.php?Validate=*  CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
```

Try this code.

Comment: It's working right now to save but since it overwrites my question is, how do I name them based on the loop count when I press the play button? Like for example name it from 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, etc. EDIT: I found it it's `{{!LOOP}}` TYVM for this :)

Comment: Also, for some reason, I saved it using Firefox browser but it seems to have more KB. However, if I saved it for Chrome it has a lower KB. Does the zoom % on the screen affect the size of the image?

Comment: Never thought about that. The size is irrelevant. JS gets the job done.